# How to read json value from returned JSON.stringify (Node Express)

Tags: json, express, templates

In my node express server.js, I have this route:

```
app.get('/athlete_id_table', function(req, res) {
  database.select('*').from('participants').then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.length) {
      res.render('athlete_id_table', {
        name: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        msg: 'Could not get athlete ID, first name and last name'
      });
    }
  }).catch(err => res.sendStatus(400))
});
```

This route returns the athlete object with id, athlete_id, email, first_name, and last_name.

In the 'athlete_id_table' hbs template, I return the stringify object and all I see on the browser is the array.

```
<body>
  {{name}}
</body>
```

Output in the browser: 
[{"id":1,"athlete_id":1,"email":"xxxx@gmail.com","first_name":"Josh","last_name":"Stern"}]

I tried adding .first_name but I get a blank page instead. Can someone tell how do I display the first name for example. For testing purposes I only have one athlete in the database.

```
<body>
  {{name.first_name}}
</body>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of stringifying, have you tried just `res.render('athlete_id_table', { name: data.first_name })`?

Comment: Just did, the browser is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is an array, not an object, so to render the name, use `{{name.[0].first_name}}`.

Comment: This gives me a parseError:

Comment: <body>
  {{name[0].first_name}}
--------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
    at Parser.parseError

Comment: @calvert see edit. The main point being that `name` is an array and not an object.

Comment: I just tried your updated edit, it works after I remove the stringify from my server.js and return the json object. I get 'Josh' which is the answer that I am looking for. Thank you very much.